# Converting an XFile type to a Multipart file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, multipart, imagepicker

Ive got a function to send 2 strings and an image to the server using hhtp.post method using REST API.The image is picked from the gallery using the Image picker package.

```
Future<ApiResponse> post(String url, dynamic body) async {
logger.i('Api Post, url $_url$url');
logger.i('Api Post, data ${body.toString()}');
ApiResponse apiResponse;
try {
  final response =
      await http.post(Uri.parse(_url + url), body: body, headers: _headers);
  apiResponse = _returnResponse(response);
} on SocketException {
  logger.e('No net');
  throw FetchDataException('No Internet connection');
}
return apiResponse;
}
```

below is my repository function

```
Future<ApiResponse> sendBankSlip(BankSlipRequest bankSlipRequest) async {
final ApiResponse apiResponse = await restServiceProvider.post("/courses/create-payment", bankSlipRequest.toJson());
return apiResponse;
```

}

below is my BankSlipRequest file,

```
import 'package:care_giver_app/models/api_request.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class BankSlipRequest extends ApiRequest{
  String courseId="";
  XFile? slip;
  String paidAmount="";

 BankSlipRequest({required this.courseId,required this.slip,required this.paidAmount});

BankSlipRequest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  courseId = json['course_Id'];
  slip = json['proof_image'];
  paidAmount = json['paid_amount'];
 }

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
   "course_Id": courseId,
   "proof_image": slip,
   "paid_amount": paidAmount,
  };
```

Right now the image is in the **XFile** format, what I want is to convert it into a **multipart** file. Please help me convert it

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering a little bit late. You will need to convert XFile to bytes and  read bytes from your backend.
Here is one of the possible solutions:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> toJsonImage() async{
    return  {
      "course_Id": courseId,
      "proof_image": await slip!.readAsBytes(),
      "paid_amount": paidAmount,
    };


Future<ApiResponse> sendBankSlip(BankSlipRequest bankSlipRequest) async {
  final ApiResponse apiResponse = await restServiceProvider.post(
      "/courses/create-payment", await bankSlipRequest.toJsonImage());
  return apiResponse;
}
```

If you have any errors, let me know.